# CREATE TABLE XX LIKE YY in two DB using Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I would like to copy all data from one DB table to another DB.

I have created two connections but am not sure of what I need to do regarding the actual SQL to make this happen.

```
$one = DB::connection('mysql');
$two = DB::connection('mysql_2');

DB::statement("CREATE TABLE {$one}.products LIKE {$two}.products;");
```

Not completely unexpectedly, the response to this is

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection could not be converted to string
```

Is this even possible between two DBs?

Besides inserting each row into the new table, what are some other options for copying a large set of data from one DB to another?

Comment: Use `$one = DB::connection('mysql')->getConfig('database');` etc.

Comment: What is the etc. part? I have the two DB connections, how can I copy a table from one to the other in the best way? Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve reading from one and looping through all the records and inserting one by one?

Comment: `$two = DB::connection('mysql_2')->getConfig('database');` You can use `INSERT INTO [...] SELECT * FROM [...]` ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)).